# Trimming/replacing inline css with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an inline css set to a span element that looks like this:

```
<span style="background-image: url(http://example.com/House-150x150.jpg)" class="list-cover has-image"></span>
```

I would like to remove the "-150150" part of it, so that i end up with something like this:

```
<span style="background-image: url(http://example.com/House.jpg)" class="list-cover has-image"></span>
```

I need it to be exlusively with JavaScript, without importing the JQuery library. I've tried to make it work in many ways but I couldn't find a way around it yet.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var span = document.querySelector(".list-cover");
span.setAttribute("style",span.getAttribute("style").replace(/-150x150/, ""));
```

```html
<span style="background-image: url(http://example.com/House-150x150.jpg)" class="list-cover has-image">Right-click and inspect to see the change</span>
```

Comment: yeah now you didnt ;-)

Comment: It looks like the right approach. However, when applying it to my website I get an error saying "cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined" .. it looks like it's not finding the right element in the DOM :/ FYI, the only way of applying a css style to these lements is by calling the span like this: "span.list-cover.has-image". If I try using ".list-cover" by itself, the styles don't apply. Do you have any idea of what would be the best way of implementing your solution in my case ? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: As you can see my code works so please post actual [mcve] with the HTML from the view-source

Comment: I can't share my files because the website is done in Wordpress, and I can't simplify them. I've figured out what my problem is. The elements that I'm trying to apply this script to, are created once the user clicks on a certain button, and not right after the page loads. I'm still not able to apply the code but I'll give you a positive review for your answer anyway. Thanks !

Comment: So find where the click is and change it there

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].getAttribute("style");
var x2 = x.replace("-150x150","");

document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("style",x2);
```

Comment: I get an error saying "cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined" .. it looks like it's not finding the element in the DOM :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegEx so it could be more dynamic:

```
var x = '<span style="background-image: url(http://example.com/House-150x150.jpg)" class="list-cover has-image"></span>';
x.replace(/(url\(.*)(\-.*)(\..*\))/i, '$1$3');
```

Here you can see what groups $1, $2, and $3 are: https://regex101.com/r/lokdTU/1